# Eclipse не видит java source code

Tags: eclipse, java

Добрый день, занимаюсь освоением Java.

jdk и jre лежат в Program Files/Java

Netbeans ("из коробки") при создании проекта подключает к нему JDK, и для любого класса из него можно посмотреть исходный код.

А вот eclipse ("из коробки") посмотреть исходный код не дает. В списке файлов проекта значится JRE, и при "ctrl+шелчок" на любом классе/методе выдает: Source not found и, к примеру ...Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar no source attachment.

Это вообще нормально, что он ссылается на отдельную jre? Ведь по идее, jre, которая входит в состав jdk и есть нужная jre, разве не так?

Не подскажете, как быть?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Для разработки надо использовать JDK, в ней есть исходный код классов. Зайди в Window-Preferences-Java-Installed JREs укажи путь к установленной JDK (например c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0).

После проверь настройки проекта: Properties-Java Build Path-Libraries и установи там правильную версию для JRE System Library

Похоже что у тебя eclipse использует для работы JRE, это можно исправить в eclipse.ini

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Erys Если ответ верный, надо принять ответ и поблагодарить мишу добавлением его репутации. Спасибо тут не канает.

Answer (score 0):

P. S. Абсолютно аналогичным способом можно подключить исходники JDK, если вы работаете чисто на Java. Для этого к библиотеке rt.jar надо подключить в качестве исходников файл src.zip, лежащий в корне папки, где уставлен ваш JDK.

[ссылка на хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/172491/)

Comment: Хотя ответ и нужно засчитать как правильный - но есть технические замечания к написанию ответа. Он, фактически, состоит из одной ссылки на внешний ресурс. А ссылки имеют свойство протухать (на том же хабре НЛО может вырезать). Поэтому рекомендую кратко описать существенную часть ответа непосредственно в самом тексте ответа. В остальном же -- добро пожаловать на руСО!